Neo4j - Vector search - Out-of-memory issue
I'd like to use the handy vector embeddings in Neo4j, but I'm getting an issue already with a simple case when searching on them. Thanks for your support !
Query
MATCH (n:Node)
CALL db.index.vector.queryNodes('value_index', 5, [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0])
YIELD node, score
RETURN node, score

Error
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope': Data cannot be cloned, out of memory.

Instance
Nb. of nodes in DB: 12048 nodes
Aura DB :
- Memory: 1GB
- CPU: 1CPU
- Storage: 2GB

Note
All vectors were initialized to [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0].
Still, I'm just asking for 5 matches here.
Thanks !

Try just getting one instead of five. Are you sure your embedding is only 4 dimensional?  Thanks

This is how the embeddings were created.
CREATE VECTOR INDEX value_index IF NOT EXISTS
FOR (n:Node)
ON n.key_embedding
OPTIONS { indexConfig: {
`vector.dimensions`: 4,
`vector.similarity_function`: 'cosine'
}}


MATCH (n:Node)
CALL db.create.setNodeVectorProperty(n,'value_embedding',[1,2,3,4])
RETURN count(*)

